# My select_and_assign_vessels function creates a loop and im not sure why. There is also a bunch of other stuff wrong im sure

Tags: python

Im trying to build a battleship game in python for my CSCE 1035 class. i can get the menu to print and it seems like it clears the create_board function but then it gets stuck in the select_and_assign_vessels function and wont move past assigning the first vessel. any help would be appreciated i also plan on sharing any solutions offered with the rest of my class as we are all struggling with this project.

```
import random

ships_total = 2
missles = 20

#create a new 8x8 game board to be passed to other functions
def create_board():
    new_board = []
    for i in range(8):
        row = ['empty'] * 8
        new_board.append(row)
    return new_board

#using the newly created game board print game board and populate it
def game_board(board, solution = False,):

 #give the function a dictionary with symbols to use for the game board   
    symbols = {
        'empty': '-',
        'miss': 'O',
        'hit': 'X',
        'aircraft carrier': 'C',
        'battleship': 'B',
        'submarine': 'S',
        'destroyer': 'D'
    }
#print the top row with column labels    
    print(' ', end=' ')
    for i in range(0, len(board[0]) + 1):
        print(str(i), end=' ')
    print()
#loop through each row and column of the board
    for i, row in enumerate(board):
        print(chr(i + ord('A')), end=' ')
        for col in row:
            if col == 'C':
                if solution == True:
                    print(symbols['aircraft carrier'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == True and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['aircraft carrier'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == False and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['hit'], end= ' ')
                else:
                    print(symbols['empty'], end= ' ')
            if col == 'B':
                if solution == True:
                    print(symbols['battleship'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == True and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['battleship'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == False and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['hit'], end= ' ')
                else:
                    print(symbols['empty'], end= ' ')
            if col == 'S':
                if solution == True:
                    print(symbols['submarine'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == True and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['submarine'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == False and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['hit'], end= ' ')
                else:
                    print(symbols['empty'], end= ' ')
            if col == 'D':
                if solution == True:
                    print(symbols['destroyer'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == True and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['destroyer'], end= ' ')
                elif solution == False and col['X']:
                    print(symbols['hit'], end= ' ')
                else:
                    print(symbols['empty'], end= ' ')
            elif col == 'hit' or col == 'miss':
                print(symbols[col], end= ' ')
            else:
                print(symbols['empty'], end= ' ')
        print()

def select_and_assign_vessels(board):
    # Define the vessels and their characteristics
    vessels = {
        'aircraft carrier': {'name': 'aircraft carrier', 'length': 5, 'hits': 5},
        'battleship': {'name': 'battleship', 'length': 4, 'hits': 4},
        'submarine': {'name': 'submarine', 'length': 3, 'hits': 3},
        'destroyer': {'name': 'destroyer', 'length': 2, 'hits': 2}
    }
    # Randomly select the first vessel and its orientation
    ship1_name = random.choice(['aircraft carrier', 'battleship'])
    ship1 = vessels[ship1_name]
    ship1['orientation'] = random.choice(['horizontal', 'vertical'])
    # Randomly select the second vessel and its orientation
    ship2_name = random.choice(['submarine', 'destroyer'])
    ship2 = vessels[ship2_name]
    ship2['orientation'] = random.choice(['horizontal', 'vertical'])
    # Place the first vessel on the board
    while True:
        # Randomly select a starting row and column
        ship1_row = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        ship1_col = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
        # Check if the ship fits on the board
        if ship1['orientation'] == 'horizontal' and ship1_col + ship1['length'] <= len(board[0]):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship1_col, ship1_col + ship1['length'] + 1):
                if board[ship1_row][i] != '-':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship1_col, ship1_col + ship1['length']):
                    board[ship1_row][i] = ship1_name
                break
        elif ship1['orientation'] == 'vertical' and ship1_row + ship1['length'] <= len(board):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship1_row, ship1_row + ship1['length'] + 1):
                if board[i][ship1_col] != '-':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship1_row, ship1_row + ship1['length']):
                    board[i][ship1_col] = ship1_name
                break
        # If the ship doesn't fit or overlaps, try again
        else:
            continue
    # Place the second vessel on the board
    while True:
        # Randomly select a starting row and column
        ship2_row = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        ship2_col = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
        # Check if the ship fits on the board
        if ship2['orientation'] == 'horizontal' and ship2_col + ship2['length'] <= len(board[0]):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship2_col, ship2_col + ship2['length'] + 1):
                if board[ship2_row][i] != '-':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship2_col, ship2_col + ship2['length']):
                    board[ship2_row][i] = ship2_name
                break
        elif ship2['orientation'] == 'vertical' and ship2_row + ship2['length'] <= len(board):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship2_row, ship2_row + ship2['length'] + 1):
                if board[i][ship2_col] != '-':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship2_row, ship2_row + ship2['length']):
                    board[i][ship2_col] = ship2_name
                break
        else:
            continue

def fire_missile(row, col, board, vessels):
    if board[row][col] != ' ':
        print('Missile already fired at this location!')
        return board, vessels
    else:
        for vessel in vessels.values():
            if (row, col) in vessel['coordinates']:
                print(f'You hit the {vessel["name"]}!')
                vessel['hits'] -= 1
                missles -= 1
                if vessel['hits'] == 0:
                    print(f'You sank the {vessel["name"]}!')
                    ships_total -= 1
                board[row][col] = 'X'
                return board, vessels
        print('You missed!')
        missles -= 1
        board[row][col] = 'O'
        return board, vessels


def play_game():
    game_on = True

    #print header
    print('+--------------------------------------------------------+')
    print('|           Computer Science and Engineering             |')
    print('|         CSCE 1035 - Computer Programming I             |')
    print('|                                                        |')
    print('+--------------------------------------------------------+')

    print('Welcome to BattleShip! Here\'s how to play: a board will be')
    print('generated that contains two hidden ships somewhere on it. You')
    print('will be given 20 missles to try and sink both ships. Both ships')
    print('will require multiple shots to take down depending on their')
    print('length. You will enter your shots using a letter A-H and a number')
    print('0-7 you will be told if your missles hit and or miss and the board')
    print('will show you as well. Well thats all have fun!!')

    while game_on == True:
        print('Would you like to play a game?')
        print('******************* M E N U *****************+')
        print('|  Select a service:                         |')
        print('|  1. New Game                               |')
        print('|  2. New Game (dev mode)                    |')
        print('|  3. Exit/Logout                            |')
        print('*********************************************+')

        selection = input('Make your choice: ')

        if selection.isdigit() and (1 <= int(selection) <= 3):

            selection = int(selection)

            if selection == 1:
                new_game_board = create_board()
                select_and_assign_vessels(new_game_board)
                print('Game Start!')
                game_board(new_game_board)

                while ships_total == 2 or missles != 0:
                    row = input('Enter the row youd like to target: ')

                    if row != ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']:
                        print('Invalid shot location')

                    col = input('Enter the column youd like to target: ')

                    if col != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]:
                        print('invalid shot location')
                
                    fire_missile(row, col, new_game_board, select_and_assign_vessels.vessels)
                    game_board(new_game_board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is stuck because of some off-by-one errors and some minor bugs (such as comparing `-` instead of `empty`):

```py
def select_and_assign_vessels(board):
    # Randomly select the first vessel and its orientation
    ship1_name = random.choice(['aircraft carrier', 'battleship'])
    ship1 = vessels[ship1_name]
    ship1['orientation'] = random.choice(['horizontal', 'vertical'])
    # Randomly select the second vessel and its orientation
    ship2_name = random.choice(['submarine', 'destroyer'])
    ship2 = vessels[ship2_name]
    ship2['orientation'] = random.choice(['horizontal', 'vertical'])
    # Place the first vessel on the board
    while True:
        # Randomly select a starting row and column
        ship1_row = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        ship1_col = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
        # Check if the ship fits on the board
        if ship1['orientation'] == 'horizontal' and ship1_col + ship1['length'] < len(board[0]):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship1_col, ship1_col + ship1['length'] + 1):
                if board[ship1_row][i] != 'empty':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship1_col, ship1_col + ship1['length'] + 1):
                    board[ship1_row][i] = ship1_name
                break
        elif ship1['orientation'] == 'vertical' and ship1_row + ship1['length'] < len(board):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship1_row, ship1_row + ship1['length'] + 1):
                if board[i][ship1_col] != 'empty':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship1_row, ship1_row + ship1['length'] + 1):
                    board[i][ship1_col] = ship1_name
                break
        # If the ship doesn't fit or overlaps, try again
        else:
            continue
    # Place the second vessel on the board
    while True:
        # Randomly select a starting row and column
        ship2_row = random.randint(0, len(board) - 1)
        ship2_col = random.randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)
        # Check if the ship fits on the board
        if ship2['orientation'] == 'horizontal' and ship2_col + ship2['length'] < len(board[0]):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship2_col, ship2_col + ship2['length'] + 1):
                if board[ship2_row][i] != 'empty':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship2_col, ship2_col + ship2['length'] + 1):
                    board[ship2_row][i] = ship2_name
                break
        elif ship2['orientation'] == 'vertical' and ship2_row + ship2['length'] < len(board):
            overlap = False
            # Check if the ship overlaps with any existing vessels
            for i in range(ship2_row, ship2_row + ship2['length'] + 1):
                if board[i][ship2_col] != 'empty':
                    overlap = True
                    break
            if not overlap:
                # Assign the ship to the board
                for i in range(ship2_row, ship2_row + ship2['length'] + 1):
                    board[i][ship2_col] = ship2_name
                break
        else:
            continue
```

There are still other bugs in the other methods, those are left as an exercise for you to finish them. All the best and hope you enjoy the process of learning and debugging in Computer Science.